# No Civi Confirmation Email After Using Paypal

Tags: paypal, receipts, confirmation

I apologize in advance, as this question seems to have been asked many times, but the answer is still not clear after looking at different responses. I am using Civi 4.7.7 and Wordpress. I am using PayPal Pro for both credit cards and PayPal, on my own website. When a client uses credit card, there is no problem, and he also receives a Civi Contribution Confirmation Email. However, when PayPal is used, a payment receipt email is generated through PayPal, but there is no Civi confirmation sent, and on the backend of Civi it says the status of the transaction is pending (incomplete transaction).

The PayPal IPN is pointing to the the homepage of my website.
Please can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Thank you!
S

Comment: Please see the related topic which might help - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7794/contribution-receipt-not-being-sent-after-paying-with-paypal?rq=1

Comment: Where is this? /media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog
Is it possible there is a civicrm bug here and who would I report this to?

Comment: For Wordpress, the log files should be in /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog. Check the latest log file and the information in the log file might help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies, but there is a known issue regarding receipts and payment recording for recurring payments.
See [CRM-18805](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18805).

[PR-8615](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8615) corrects this and is scheduled to be merged into the 4.7.10 release, or you can apply it yourself to 4.7.6.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure if this would happen with current payments as we are just starting out and don't yet have recurring payments.